# How do I return a column from an aggregate subquery to the outer select statement that is using GROUP BY?

Tags: sql, subquery

I want to get better at subqueries which is why I am not using CTEs...
I want to generate a table of unique agent IDs that shows count of transactions, sum of sales volume and sum of commission. I also want to show those same three aggregate columns in that table where the city equals x, y and z.

```
SELECT 
  agent_id
  , COUNT(transaction_id) AS count_all
  , (SELECT
       COUNT(transaction_id)
     FROM table1
     WHERE city = 'x'
     GROUP BY agent_id) AS count_x
FROM table1
GROUP BY agent_id
```

This is an example of what I wrote but I get an error returning "Single-row subquery returns more than one row".

Comment: The inner query returns one row for each agent because you are using group by agent.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL asistance.

Comment: BTW, the subquery needs to be correlated. And skip its GROUP BY.

Comment: you can check now

Comment: Thanks for the help, @FaizunFaria. I just found out that Snowflake does not support correlated subqueries in the SELECT statement which should have been something I researched from the start!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  t1.agent_id
  , COUNT(DISTINCT t1.transaction_id) AS count_all
  , (SELECT
       COUNT(DISTINCT transaction_id)
     FROM table1
     WHERE city = 'x'
     AND agent_id = t1.agent_id) AS count_x
  , (SELECT
       COUNT(DISTINCT transaction_id)
     FROM table1
     WHERE city = 'y'
     AND agent_id = t1.agent_id) AS count_y
  , (SELECT
       COUNT(DISTINCT transaction_id)
     FROM table1
     WHERE city = 'z'
     AND agent_id = t1.agent_id) AS count_z
  , SUM(sales_volume) AS total_sales
FROM table1 t1
GROUP BY t1.agent_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing but this is not working for me. When I run this I get an error thrown that says "'t1.agent_id' in select clause is neither an aggregate nor in the group by clause".